# What function can I call if create a object of a class that is inherited from interface?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

```
public Interface IPerson 
{   
    void SetAge(int age);
}

public class Man : IPerson
{
    public void SetAge(int age) {}
    public int GetAge() {return 20; }
}

IPerson p = new Man();
```

Which functions can we call using p? Since the object of man has been created then it would be calling both functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "both methods"? There´s actually only a single method existing on the interface. Anyway: why not just try it out? Would have been far faster than writing this question, wouldn´t it?

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `SetAge`, since this is the only method defined in interface `IPerson`. So if you have declared a variable that can hold a reference to an object that implements this interface, the only method that we expect there for sure at this point is `SetAge`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `SetAge(int age)` method using interface reference. No other methods are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

As the object 'p' is of type 'IPerson', so you can only call methods which are under IPerson. Here 'SetAge' is the only method defined inside Interface IPerson.